# How to fix the Android error "Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent {...}"

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, runtime-error, android-broadcast

So I'm programming an Android app that uses Bluetooth discovery of devices. Here is the code I use to start discovery.

```
try {
    myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    Log.d("Bluetooth Started successfully","yes");
} catch (Error e) {
    Log.d("FAILED","Ya failed mate");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I then register a BroadcastReceiver to watch for when devices are found. Here is my code for that

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
final ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringArrayList);
final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d("ACTION RECEIVED","Action was received");
    Log.d("Device Name", String.valueOf(intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)));
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        stringArrayList.add(device.getName());
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.invalidateViews();
    }
    }
};
registerReceiver(myReceiver,intentFilter);
```

The listView, arrayAdapter, and stringArrayList are just things I'm "logging" to.

The problem is that whenever I run that code I get this error and my code doesn't function. I'm assuming that the reason it doesn't function is because of this error.

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED flg=0x10 } to com.verizon.messaging.vzmsgs/com.verizon.vzmsgs.receiver.DevicePairingListener
```

Can someone tell me what this error means as well as how to fix it?

I also find other questions on Stack Overflow with errors that look very similar; like, instead of Bluetooth, it will be in the context of BOOT_COMPLETED, ACTION_POWER_DISCONECTED, or BATTERY_LOW. How are those similar to this.

Comment: Please post your manifest. Do you have a `<receiver>` declared in the manifest with an `<intent-filter>` containing `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED`?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I think it's because of Implicit Broadcast Ban of Android O , to solve this you can make your targetSDKVersion be less than 26 . You can find more here https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html

Comment: According to this there isn't a way around it though. Is that really true?

Comment: It's ok when you register the receiver in the code , I have download this code https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat , and I can get a callback in the BroadcastReceiver , maybe you can compare to the project to find where is the problem in your project .  I noticed there are two permissions declared in the manifest . android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and android.permission.BLUETOOTH , you can check this first.

Comment: Using a lower target is not a solution.

Comment: It does not a solution

Comment: maybe it's not a solution, but it does explain the problem unlike the answer below. And solutions are there if you follow the link

Comment: This is not a solution, you have to be forced to upgrade your targetSDKVersion :D

Answer (score 15):

In my case - Android 9 (API level 28) I had to define my `BroadcastReceiver` inside the code only to make it work.

Like this (added inside a service in my case - its not matter)

```
private MyReceiver myReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.myreceiver"));
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}

private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.myreceiver")) {
                //logic goes here
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //some log goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Send the broadcast like this

```
Intent intentMy = new Intent();
intentMy.setAction("android.intent.action.myreceiver");
intentMy.putExtra("whatever", true);
sendBroadcast(intentMy);
```

Comment: That was indeed the issue. It's a weird error message for sure!

Answer (score 12):

[Implicit](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) broadcasts are not allowed anymore in Android Oreo and later.

An implicit broadcast is a broadcast that does not target that app specifically.

Instead of just using the intent-filter action name for constructing the Intent, search the package manager for the component providing the broadcast receiver:

```java
            Intent intent = new Intent("the intent-filter action name in the different app").setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> infos = packageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
                ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(info.activityInfo.packageName,
                        info.activityInfo.name);
                intent.setComponent(cn);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It work for me, call function receiveData in your Activity

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == "com.myapp.SEND_DATA") {
            val data = intent.getStringExtra("data")
            Log.d("MyBroadcastReceiver", "==============> Data received:  $data")
        }
    }
}

  private fun receiveData() {
        val filter = IntentFilter("com.myapp.SEND_DATA")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
            }
            startForegroundService(Intent(this, MyForegroundService::class.java))
        }
    }
```

Class MyForegroundService

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

class MyForegroundService : Service() {

    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "MyForegroundServiceChannel"
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("broadcast_intent")) {
            val broadcastIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra<Intent>("broadcast_intent")
            broadcastIntent?.let { handleBroadcastIntent(it) }
        }

        // Create a notification for the foreground service
        val notification = createNotification()

        // Start the service in the foreground
        startForeground(1, notification)

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    private fun handleBroadcastIntent(intent: Intent) {
        // Handle the broadcast intent as needed
        // This is where you process the received data

        val receivedData = intent.getStringExtra("key_data")
        // Process or broadcast the data as needed
        // For example, send a local broadcast, update UI, etc.
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)  // Change to the actual MainActivity of your app
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            notificationIntent,
            0
        )

        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText("Service is running in the foreground")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)  // Replace with your notification icon
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```